# The associative operad with more elements still associative?

Tags: abstract-algebra, operads

So the associative operad is defined as $P(n) = a_n$ for each $n$. What happens if we set $P(3) = a_3$ but add more elements to the other $P(n)$ for example if $P(5) = \{x,y,z\} $. Will an algebra over this still be an associative algebra?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you only have one element in $P(2)$ and $P(3)$, any algebra over this operad will have an associative binary product (the product is the realization of the element in $P(2)$, and the fact that there is only one element in $P(3)$ shows that this product is associative).

If you add extra operations in higher arity, then the algebras will also have other operations, which may or may not be related to the binary product depending on the relations you put in your operad.

Note that of course once you add those operations, you have to put in your operad all the ways they combine with each other.

Comment: Will the Generalized associative law still be true for the binary operation for an algebra over this operad?

Comment: I think you are maybe too invested in the abstract "operad theory" part to see the obvious: if a binary product is associative for three elements, it is associative. The first year college proof still works. In operad theory terms, there will be an element $a_n$ in each $P(n)$, and all possible compositions of $a_2$ with arity $n$ will be equal to $a_n$ (but there may or may not be other elements too).

Comment: Alright, yes your right, that does make total sense.